# Bundle cannot find gem 'simple-form' Rails 4.1 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

The issue I have in my title does not just apply to simple-form but to a number of gems that I'm trying to install using bundle (factorygirl,rspec,etc.). I've looked into this question and have found these links:

[Bundler can't find compatible version of rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597361/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-activesupport)

[Bundler can't find sql lite 3 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416016/could-not-find-gem-sqlite3-0-ruby)

[Gemfile can't find gems](http://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1767)

The specific error that I get is this:

```
Could not find gem 'simple-form (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this
machine.
```

Here is what I've tried:

1. Bundle Install
2. Bundle Update
3. I've actually copy and pasted simple-form (>= 0) ruby in my gemfile
4. Looked up platformatec for any reference. Found nothing of note.
5. Rails 4.1 guide. Unless I missed something I don't think it has anything to do with my  problem.
6. Gem Update Rails
7. Made sure my Gemfile.lock points to the right rails version.

I don't know what the problem is, I didn't really try the recommendations on the third link because it was a little too technical for my taste going into internals. As a newcomer to technology, that would be a recipe for failure. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I put gem simple-form instead of gem simple_form.